# JavaScript method invocations

Tags: javascript

In the book "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th edition", on page 61, section 4.5 Invocation Expressions, it says -

> In method invocations, the object or array that is the **subject** of
>   the property access becomes the value of the `this` parameter while
>   the function is being executed.

Can someone, in plain english, explain the meaning of that statement, and maybe give an example? 
I especially don't know what is meant by the "**subject** of the property access" means.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of 'this' is that 'this' is the context of the function during its execution.
Unless you explicitely change 'this', the default behaviour is that the context of the function during its execution is the context of the function call.

First case (most simple) :

```
var writeHelloFromThis = function() {
       console.log('hello from ' + this);
 };

writeHelloFromThis();
```

--> the output is "hello from [object Window]", since the context of the call was the global object i.e. Window.

Second case : now we define an object, and add the writeHelloFromThis to it :

```
var anObject={};

anObject.writeHelloFromThis = writeHelloFromThis;
```

and now we call writeHelloFromThis with anObject as context :

```
anObject.writeHelloFromThis();
```

--> the output is "hello from [object Object]" : this was the function call's context : anObject in this case.

3rd case, a little bit trickier : now we will store the writeHelloFromThis of 'anObject' into another var :

```
var anObjectsWriteHelloFromThis = anObject.writeHelloFromThis;
```

anObjectsWriteHelloFromThis just stores a function (=a reference) without knowing anything about 'anObject'. So if we call :

```
 anObjectsWriteHelloFromThis();
```

the output will be "hello from [object Window]", since the context of the call was the global object i.e. Window.

Last remark : if this way of proceeding seems limitative to you, you're right : that's why some Function methods : bind, call, apply, allows you to change the context of the function.

so one last example :

```
 writeHelloFromThis.call(anObject);
```

will have the output "hello from [object Object]", and not windows, since here we force 'this' to be anObject.

Comment: you're welcome :-) I might add a thing or two when i have time in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (for now), `this` is determined by *how* a function is called, not how the function is defined. What Flanagan is saying is that given this:

```
foo.bar();
```

...during the call to `bar`, `this` will refer to the object referenced by `foo`.

If you're coming from some other languages like Java or C#, you may think, "But surely `this` always refers to `foo` within `bar`" but that's not the case in JavaScript. Example:

```
var f = foo.bar; // Get a reference to the function, but not calling it
f();             // Now we call it
```

In the above, `this` within the call to `bar` is **not** `foo`, it's the global object (if you're not in strict mode) or `undefined` (if you are).

More (on my blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: Thanks T.J.! can you tell me what you mean when you say - "object referenced by foo"? What "object" are you referring to?

Comment: @ABogus: Using a concrete example: `var a = []; a.push('test');` During the call to `push`, `this` will refer to the array that `a` refers to. For my `foo` example, it might be an object created via a constructor function, or just an object that has a `bar` function directly assigned to it: `var foo = {name: 'foo', bar: function() { alert("I'm " + this.name); }};`

Answer (score 0):

To complement T.J.'s answer, here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Adf4k/):

```
var o = {}; // define an object
o.name = 'foo'; // add an attribute to the object
var f = function() { // define a function
    return this.name; // the function uses this internally
}
o.someFunction = f; // add the function to the object
var result = o.someFunction();
```

now the value of `result` is `'foo'` because the function has been invoked on the object o, and inside the function, `this` refers to the object on which the function has been invoked.